# horizon ingest_latest_ledger doesn't update

Tags: horizon

I just run a new horizon instance. 
The horizon instance with `Ingest=true` is running this command: `horizon db reingest range 1 latest && horizon serve`

I can see the `history_latest_ledger` changes but the `ingest_latest_ledger` doesn't change and it's equal to zero.

Would anybody know if this is normal and the `ingest_latest_ledger` gets change when the reingest is done or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem but `history_latest_ledger` isn't changing either.